# How do i syntax in haskell

Tags: haskell

Im trying to write a function that takes in a string and then returns the string as a list of string-words (like the words built-in function) and so far i've written

```
ord :: String -> [String]
ord [] = []
ord xs = let
    ys = groupBy (\x y -> y /= ' ') xs
    in filter (not . null) ys
```

I thougth this would get rid of the empty strings from the list but i only get this output

input:

```
ord  “aa b       c   -    dd”
```

output:

```
["aa"," b"," "," "," "," "," "," "," c"," "," "," -"," "," "," "," dd"]
```

when this is the output i want:

```
[“aa”, ”b”, ”c”, ”-“, ”dd”]
```

I get the same result if i try and write

```
ord :: String -> [String]
ord [] = []
ord xs = filter (not . null) ys
    where
        ys = groupBy (\x y -> y /= ' ') xs
```

How do i re-write this code so that i rid the list of its empty strings? 
Or use the proper syntax? Im just learning Haskell and im still having trouble with the syntax...

Comment: There are no problems with syntax here—the compiler would tell you so. Rewrite the code to omit strings which contain only a space, and note that some strings start with a space.

Comment: If you want to use `groupBy` to throw all the spaces into their own groups, you need to look at `x` as well. Otherwise the spaces gets grouped together with the non-space after it.  And `null` checks for empty strings (zero characters), not blank strings (only space).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`groupBy` means that you put `x` and `y` in the same group, given the condition is satisfied. But here you group the two together, given `y` is not equal to a space.

You thus can alter your grouping predicate, and put `x` and `y` in the same group, given both are spaces, or non-spaces:

```
import Data.Char(isSpace)

ord :: String -> [String]
ord [] = []
ord xs = let
    ys = groupBy (\x y -> isSpace x == isSpace y) xs
    in filter (not . null) ys
```

or shorter:

```
import Data.Char(isSpace)
import Data.Function(on)

ord :: String -> [String]
ord [] = []
ord xs = let
    ys = groupBy (on (==) isSpace) xs
    in filter (not . null) ys
```

Now we retrieve:

```
Prelude Data.List> ord "aa b       c   -    dd"
["aa"," ","b","       ","c","   ","-","    ","dd"]
```

We of course still not obtain the expected result. In stead of filtering out empty strings, we can filter out strings that only contain spacing characters:

```
import Data.Char(isSpace)
import Data.Function(on)

ord :: String -> [String]
ord [] = []
ord xs = let
    ys = groupBy (on (==) isSpace) xs
    in filter (not . all isSpace) ys
```

We do not need to covert the empty case manually, since `groupBy` on an empty list produces an empty list, we can thus construct a one liner to do the processing:

```
import Data.Char(isSpace)
import Data.Function(on)

ord :: String -> [String]
ord = filter (not . all isSpace) . groupBy (on (==) isSpace)
```

Then we obtain the expected result:

```
Prelude Data.List Data.Char> ord "aa b       c   -    dd"
["aa","b","c","-","dd"]
```

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't bother with `groupBy` at all here. In particular, there's no need to build lists of spaces just to throw them away. Let's start with a function that drops initial spaces and then grabs everything to the first space:

```
grab :: String -> (String, String)
grab = break isSpace . dropWhile isSpace
```

Note that the first component of `grab xs` will be empty if and only if all the elements of `xs` are spaces.

Now we can write

```
myWords :: String -> [String]
myWords xs = case grab xs of
  ([], _) -> []
  (beginning, end) -> beginning : myWords end
```